# Asymptotic variance of an estimator

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, parameter-estimation

Suppose we have an estimator (i.e. a sequence of estimators) $T_n$ which is asymptotically normal, in the sense that $\sqrt{n}(T_n - \theta)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. The variance $\sigma^2$ is usually called the asymptotic variance of the estimator, but can we write that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\textrm{Var}[\sqrt{n}T_n]=\sigma^2$ ? If not, what additional conditions on the sequence $T_n$ we would need in order to do so ? Are consistency of $T_n$ and uniform integrability of $T_n^2$ sufficient conditions ?

Comment: Large sample variance of $T_n$ is $\sigma^2/n$, so shouldn't asymptotic variance be $0$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $\mathrm{Var}(\sqrt{n} T_n) = n \mathrm{Var}(T_n) = n\sigma^2/n = \sigma^2.$ Edit: as for the name "asymptotic variance", language varies, but referring to $\lim_n n \mathrm{Var}(T_n)$ as the asymptotic variance of an estimator $T_n$ is common (because it allows you to compare estimators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get away with anything less than the uniform integrability of $(\sqrt{n} (T_n - \theta))^2$ and its weak convergence to $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Note that if $T_n = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$ for some iid $\xi_i$ with $E \xi_1 = 0$ and $E \xi_1^2 < \infty$, then $(\sqrt{n} T_n)^2$ is uniformly integrable (why?). There should also be a one-liner way of doing this, by appeal to some convergence theorem, or else using a trick like Skorokhod's representation theorem. I would be curious to know a shorter way; below is the "direct" analysis way.

Let $Y_n = \sqrt{n}(T_n - \theta)$ and let $Y$ be $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. The weak convergence of $Y_n$ to $Y$ means that, for any bounded continuous function $f$ (I write $f \in C_b$), $E[f(Y_n)] \rightarrow E[f(Y)].$ Unfortunately, the function $f(y) = y^2$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. We will have to approximate $f(y)$ by a sequence $\{f_M\} \subset C_b$ and take limits; this is where uniform integrability of $Y_n^2$ will come in.

For $0 < M < \infty$, define $f_M(y) = y^2 \wedge M$, and note that $f_M \in C_b$. We wish to show that $E[f(Y_n)] \rightarrow E[f(Y)]$, where $f(y) = y^2$. We have, for any $M$,
\begin{align*}
|E[f(Y_n)] - E[f(Y)]| &\leq |E[f(Y_n)] - E[f_M(Y_n)]| \tag{1}\\
&+ |E[f_M(Y_n)] - E[f_M(Y)]| \tag{2}\\
&+ |E[f_M(Y)] - E[f(Y)]|. \tag{3} 
\end{align*}
We will use uniform integrability to pick an $M$ which bounds the first and the last term uniformly in $n$. Then, for fixed $M$, we can pick $n$ large enough to make the middle term as small as desired using the weak convergence of $Y_n$ to $Y$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\{Y_n^2\}_{n\geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable, so is $\{Y_n^2\}_{n \geq 1} \cup \{Y^2\}$. By uniform integrability, there is $M \in (0, \infty)$ such that
$$\sup_{n \geq 1} E[1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\} Y_n^2] < \varepsilon/8, \quad E[1\{Y^2 \geq M\} Y^2] < \varepsilon/8.\tag{4}$$
Fix such an $M$ once and for all. By the weak convergence of $Y_n$ to $Y$, for the  fixed function $f_M \in C_b$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N<\infty$ depending only on $f_M$ and $\varepsilon$ such that, for all $n \geq N$,
$$|E[f_M(Y_n)] - E[f_M(Y)]| \leq \varepsilon/2.\tag{5}$$
We have set our estimates, and what follows below holds for the given $\varepsilon > 0$, and any $n \geq N$.

To use $(4)$ in $(1)$, note that
\begin{align}
&\quad|E[f(Y_n)] - E[f_M(Y_n)]| \\
&= E[(f(Y_n) - f_M(Y_n))1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}|] + E[(f(Y_n) - f_M(Y_n))1\{Y_n^2 < M\}|] .\tag{6} 
\end{align}
The first term in $(6)$ is restricted to the event $\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}$,  and  each term  $f(Y_n)$ and $f_M(Y_n)$ contributes little to the expectation: we have for any $n \geq 1$,
$$E[f(Y_n) 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}] = E[Y_n^2 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}] < \varepsilon/8,\tag{7}$$
and also notice that the pointwise inequality $(Y_n^2 \wedge M) 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\} \leq Y_n^2 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}$, which gives
$$E[f_M(Y_n) 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}] \leq E[Y_n^2 1\{Y_n^2 \geq M\}] < \varepsilon/8.\tag{8}$$
The second term in $(6)$ requires the cancellation of $f(Y_n)$ and $f_M(Y_n)$. However, it occurs on the event $\{Y_n^2 < M\}$, so we have the pointwise equality $(Y_n^2 \wedge M) 1\{Y_n^2 < M\} = Y_n^2 1\{Y_n^2 < M\}$, and so in fact the second term in $(6)$ is zero. Applying the triangle inequality on the first term of $(6)$ and using $(7)$ and $(8)$, we find $|E[f(Y_n) - f_M(Y_n)]| < \varepsilon/4$.

The same argument as was applied to use $(4)$ in $(1)$ can be recycled to use $(4)$ in $(3)$, and estimate $|E[f_M(Y)] - E[f(Y)]| < \varepsilon/4$. Finally, we can use $(5)$ directly in $(2)$ to deduce that, for all $n \geq N$,
$$|E[f(Y_n)] - E[f(Y)]| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$
This is what we wanted, since for any centered random variable $Z$,
$$E[f(Z)] = E[Z^2] = \mathrm{Var}(Z).$$

Such a result must be true, and probably under milder conditions, because one can even numerically estimate the asymptotic variance in (well-converged) Markov chains. A general statement can probably be found somewhere in Meyn & Tweedie's book on stochastic stability.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate proof. Note that $\sqrt{n}(T_n-\theta)$ converging in distribution towards $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ does not mean that it is a centered random variable. In fact, the scenario I had in mind was the convergence in distribution stated by the Delta method after applying a smooth function to an ordinary i.i.d. type estimator, in which case $T_n$ might only be asymptotically unbiased. Also, proving uniform integrability of a sequence that has a growing factor of $n$ that cannot be immediately neutralized seems hopeless.

Comment: Re: the asymptotic bias, if you give me some time I should be able to amend that (probably not this week). It shouldn't be an issue, because bias should decay fast enough that the error between the second moment and the variance goes to $0$. As for uniform integrability, note that  for the sample mean, $E[(\sqrt{n}T_n)^2|] = n E[n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i^2 +2\sum_{i < j} \xi_i \xi_j]  = \sum_i E\xi_1^2 / n = E\xi_1^2$, so the sample mean is $L^2$-bounded; it is also uniformly absolutely continuous, hence u.i. The case you mention should follow fairly quickly from what was established above.

Comment: Yes, there is no issue with the mean of an i.i.d. sample - that is the most basic example. But, what about applying the function $h(x)=1/x$ to $n^{-1}\sum \xi_i$ with $E\xi_i = \theta > 0$ and proving uniform integrability of $n[h(n^{-1}\sum \xi_i) - h(\theta)]^2$ ?

Answer (score -1):

Let me try the following:

$\sigma^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\textrm{Var}[\sqrt{n}(T_n-\theta)]=\lim_{n\to\infty}(E[n(T_n-\theta)^2]-(E[\sqrt{n}(T_n-\theta)])^2)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(E[(T_n-\theta)^2]-E[T_n-\theta]^2)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(E[T_n^2]+\theta^2-2\theta E[T_n]-(E[T_n]^2+\theta^2-2\theta E[T_n]))$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(E[T_n^2]-E[T_n]^2)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}nVar(T_n)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}Var(\sqrt{n}T_n)$

I only used that $\theta$ is a constant so i guess we don't need further assumptions.

Comment: How do you justify your first equality ? That is precisely my question - the variances of $\sqrt{n}(T_n - \theta)$ and $\sqrt{n}T_n$ are the same.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood the question. Convergence in distribution does not imply convergence of the moments.